# Displaying all Intel CPU types as various option values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have 8 option boxes on my UI that I'm designing. The goal is to have the dropdowns ask what CPU your computer has and auto populate the rest of the information.

I have code that will populate the dropdowns with "Intel", then display "Intel Family" (Core i7), but I need that to then ask what processor it has. This is going to be a large amount of information, as an Intel i7 has 77 Different versions. Just like an i3,i5,i9.In total there are 693 unique options.

e.g.

```
Intel > Core i7 > 7700

Intel > Core i3 > 9300...
```

I just have my data stored on excel in a pivot table but I'm assuming ill need it in a JSON file which I'm not familiar with yet.

I have a screenshot of what I'm trying to explain, but the code at the moment is very messy.

[image: CPU Image]

[image: CPU-Intel-i7 Image]

Here is my current code with JS,

https://jsfiddle.net/f745nq0b/2/

```js
$('#env-select').on('change', function(e) {
  var source = $(this),
    val = $.trim(source.val()),
    target = $('#family-select');
  $(target).empty();
  if (typeof(_data[val]) != "undefined") {
    var options = (typeof(_data[val]) != "undefined") ? _data[val] : {};
    $('<option>-- Select --</option>').appendTo(target);
    $.each(options, function(value, index) {
      $('<option value="' + value + '">' + index + '</option>').appendTo(target);
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.form-control {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script>
      var _data = {};
      var _data = {
        "Intel": {
          "Celeron": "Celeron",
          "Celeron D": "Celeron D",
          "Celeron Dual-Core": "Celeron Dual-Core",
          "Celeron M": "Celeron M",
          "Core 2 Duo": "Core 2 Duo",
          "Core 2 Extreme": "Core 2 Extreme",
          "Core 2 Quad": "Core 2 Quad",
          "Core i3": "Core i3",
          "Core i5": "Core i5",
          "Core i7": "Core i7",
          "Core i7 Extreme Edition": "Core i7 Extreme Edition",
          "Core i9": "Core i9",
          "Core i9 Extreme Edition": "Core i9 Extreme Edition",
          "Pentium": "Pentium",
          "Pentium 4": "Pentium 4",
          "Pentium D": "Pentium D",
          "Pentium Dual-Core": "Pentium Dual-Core",
          "Pentium Extreme Edition": "Pentium Extreme Edition",
          "Pentium III": "Pentium III",
        },
        "AMD": {
          "APU A10-Series": "APU A10-Series",
          "APU A12 Series": "APU A12 Series",
          "APU A4-Series": "APU A4-Series",
          "APU A6-Series": "APU A6-Series",
          "APU A8-Series": "APU A8-Series",
          "APU E-Series": "APU E-Series",
          "Athlon": "Athlon",
          "Athlon 64": "Athlon 64",
          "Athlon 64 X2": "Athlon 64 X2",
          "Athlon Dual Core": "Athlon Dual Core",
          "Athlon II": "Athlon II",
          "Athlon X2 Series": "Athlon X2 Series",
          "Athlon X4 Series": "Athlon X4 Series",
          "Athlon XP": "Athlon XP",
          "Duron": "Duron",
          "FX": "FX",
          "K6": "K6",
          "Opteron": "Opteron",
          "Phenom": "Phenom",
          "Phenom II": "Phenom II",
          "Ryzen 3": "Ryzen 3",
          "Ryzen 5": "Ryzen 5",
          "Ryzen 7": "Ryzen 7",
          "Ryzen 9": "Ryzen 9",
          "Sempron": "Sempron",
          "Threadripper": "Threadripper",
        }
      };

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="advanced_search_container">
      <div class="advanced_search_title">
        <span>Search for CPU</span>
      </div>
      <lable>Type</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="env-select">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
        <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
      </select>
      <lable>Family</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="family-select">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
      </select>
      <lable>Processor</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="processor-select">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <lable>Codename</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="codename-autoselect">
        <option value="">Auto Selected</option>
      </select>
      <lable>Frequency</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="frequency">
        <option value="">Auto Selected</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <lable>CPU Cores</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="cpu-cores">
        <option value="">Auto Selected</option>
      </select>
      <lable>CPU Threads</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="cpu-threads">
        <option value="">Auto Selected</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <lable>CPU Memory</lable>
      <select class="form-control" id="cpu-memory">
        <option value="">Auto Selected</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do you foresee finding the various pieces of information ~ the 693 unique options? Or is ALL the information already in the xls/csv file?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have the data stored on an xls document.

Comment: Here is the link to the document which has the list of all Intel CPU's   
[link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsGiYydcmcP5gTyJRH9ZbI5d_kki?e=aOh5nV)

Comment: Took ages to open that file btw but copied the content. Do you have PHP available on the server?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the PHP is a work in progress at the moment, we will have it but for the meantime it just stored on the xls

Comment: I notice that the dropdown menus include a `threads` yet no such field exists within the XLS data - is that to be ignored?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes i need to find the data along with what the code name will be. Unfortunately the information has to be manually populated. Threads can be ignored, but codenames will need to be populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the [cited XLS file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsGiYydcmcP5gTyJRH9ZbI5d_kki?e=aOh5nV) and converting that to [a JSON file](https://pastebin.com/X9TzHL3Q) using some simple PHP:

```
# codenames are based upon this array - for the dummy data only
$dictionary=[
    'degree','bicone','moneme','ibexes','eringo','dallan','condit','result','pyrene','joffre','humour','reemit','phenix',
    'naseby','baffle','melder','crakow','anvers','swatch','snoozy','joanne','mitzie','bogong','steels','uniate','vestry',
    'astron','fascia','murine','galosh','mudded','nebula','enmity','advert','pewter','jequi','waggon','sneesh','phuket',
    'ifugao','elsene','bailie','outman','acetum','zillah','lauric','unnigh'
];
# function to build the dummy codename.
function gencodename(){
    global $dictionary;
    $a=mt_rand(0,count($dictionary)-1);
    $b=mt_rand(1,9);
    $c=chr( mt_rand(65,90) );
    return sprintf('%s-%s%s',$dictionary[$a],$b,$c);
}



# The saved CSV file taken from the original XLS.
$file='cpu-info.csv';

$out=array();
$csv=new SplFileObject( $file );
$csv->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_CSV );

foreach( $csv as $index => $line ){
    if( $index > 1 && !empty( $line ) && array_key_exists( 1, $line ) && array_key_exists( 2, $line ) ){
        /*
            No fields for threads or codename so we generate our own numpty values.
            Otherwise extend the below list(a,b,c,d,e....)=$line to include more vars
            & use those values rather than the dummy ones.
        */
        list( $family, $processor, $codename, $speed, $cores, $memory, $notes )=$line;
        $out[]=array(
            'processor' =>  $processor,
            'family'    =>  $family,
            'frequency' =>  $speed,
            'memory'    =>  $memory,
            'cores'     =>  $cores,
            'notes'     =>  $notes,
            'codename'  =>  gencodename(),
            'threads'   =>  mt_rand(1,16)
        );
    }
}
$json=sprintf('const json=%s;', json_encode( $out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );
$file='cpu-extra.js';
file_put_contents( $file, $json );
```

I note that the source XLS file has changed since first inspection and now has some rudimentary attempts at generating JSON strings using [concatenation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) so it should be noted that the order within the PHP code above within `list($a,$b..)=$line` etc is dependant upon the column order in the spreadsheet/csv file!

With the JSON data saved as `cpu-extra.js` within the same working directory as the HTML that follows I believe you get the desired output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body *{
                box-sizing:border-box;
                font-family:monospace;
            }
            .form-control {
                margin:0.25rem;
                padding:0.5rem;
                background:whitesmoke;
            }
            section{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                background:white;
            }
            label{ 
                flex:1;
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                justify-content:space-between;
                align-content:center;
                align-items:center;
                padding:0.25rem;
                max-width:33.4%;
            }
            .advanced_search_container{
                width:50%;
                border:1px solid black;
                border-radius:1rem;
                padding:1rem;
                background:whitesmoke;
            }
            select{
                min-width:140px;
                background:white!important;
            }
            .advanced_search_title{
                margin:0 0 1rem;
                background:whitesmoke;
            }
            .advanced_search_title > span{
                font-size:150%;
                font-weight:bolder;
            }
            .active{
                border:1px solid yellowgreen;
            }
            
            section.notes,
            section.notes label{ max-width:100% }
            
            textarea{
                width:83%;
                resize:none;
                height:5rem;
                
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
        <div class="advanced_search_container">
        
          <div class="advanced_search_title">
            <span>Search for CPU</span>
          </div>
          
          <!--
          
            Important to note that the names of the select
            menus are keys within the individual JSON records.
            
            The JSON used was created in PHP after fudging around
            with the raw XLS file cited in link. The XLS file was
            used to generate a simple CSV file which is easily read
            in PHP.
            
            Some parts of the generated JSON are nonsense - added only 
            so that the menus received some content. Items such as 
            "codename" and "threads" are ALL bogus unless by accident.
            
            Each Select menu has the ID removed as they served no purpose 
            in this code and some have new classes assigned. Menus are 
            grouped within `section` elements according to previous `break` 
            tags - mostly.
            
            Modifying this DOM structure will have unforseen effects
            upon the javascript below.
            
          -->
          
          <section class='controls'>
              <label>Type:
                  <select class="form-control" id="env-select" data-next='family' data-recycle='true'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>-- Select --
                    <option>Intel
                    <option>AMD
                  </select>
              </label>
              
              <label>Family:
                  <select class="form-control" name='family' data-next='processor' data-recycle='true'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>-- Select --
                  </select>
              </label>
              
              <label>Processor:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='processor'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>-- Select --
                  </select>
              </label>
          </section>
          
          <section class='details'>
              <label>Codename:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='codename'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Auto Selected
                  </select>
              </label>
              
              <label>Frequency:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='frequency'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Auto Selected
                  </select>
                  
              </label>
              
              <label>CPU Cores:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='cores'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Auto Selected
                  </select>
              </label>
          </section>
          
          <section class='details'>
              <label>CPU Threads:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='threads'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Auto Selected
                  </select>
              </label>
              
              <label>CPU Memory:
                  <select class="form-control dependant" name='memory'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Auto Selected
                  </select>
              </label>
          </section>
          
          <section class='notes'>
            <label>Notes:
                <textarea name='notes' class='dependant'></textarea>
            </label>
          </section>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <!--
            cpu-extra.js contains the PHP generated JSON data.
            This could be generated "on-the-fly" using PHP or
            other server side language that can read the csv 
            file.
        -->
        <script src='cpu-extra.js'></script>
        <script>

            var _data = {
              "Intel": {
                "Celeron": "Celeron",
                "Celeron D": "Celeron D",
                "Celeron Dual-Core": "Celeron Dual-Core",
                "Celeron M": "Celeron M",
                "Core 2 Duo": "Core 2 Duo",
                "Core 2 Extreme": "Core 2 Extreme",
                "Core 2 Quad": "Core 2 Quad",
                "Core i3": "Core i3",
                "Core i5": "Core i5",
                "Core i7": "Core i7",
                "Core i7 Extreme Edition": "Core i7 Extreme Edition",
                "Core i9": "Core i9",
                "Core i9 Extreme Edition": "Core i9 Extreme Edition",
                "Pentium": "Pentium",
                "Pentium 4": "Pentium 4",
                "Pentium D": "Pentium D",
                "Pentium Dual-Core": "Pentium Dual-Core",
                "Pentium Extreme Edition": "Pentium Extreme Edition",
                "Pentium III": "Pentium III",
              },
              "AMD": {
                "APU A10-Series": "APU A10-Series",
                "APU A12 Series": "APU A12 Series",
                "APU A4-Series": "APU A4-Series",
                "APU A6-Series": "APU A6-Series",
                "APU A8-Series": "APU A8-Series",
                "APU E-Series": "APU E-Series",
                "Athlon": "Athlon",
                "Athlon 64": "Athlon 64",
                "Athlon 64 X2": "Athlon 64 X2",
                "Athlon Dual Core": "Athlon Dual Core",
                "Athlon II": "Athlon II",
                "Athlon X2 Series": "Athlon X2 Series",
                "Athlon X4 Series": "Athlon X4 Series",
                "Athlon XP": "Athlon XP",
                "Duron": "Duron",
                "FX": "FX",
                "K6": "K6",
                "Opteron": "Opteron",
                "Phenom": "Phenom",
                "Phenom II": "Phenom II",
                "Ryzen 3": "Ryzen 3",
                "Ryzen 5": "Ryzen 5",
                "Ryzen 7": "Ryzen 7",
                "Ryzen 9": "Ryzen 9",
                "Sempron": "Sempron",
                "Threadripper": "Threadripper",
              }
            };
            

            /*
                shorthand utility functions
            */
            const d=document;
            const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
            const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);
            
            /*
                nodelist of ALL select menus
            */
            const col=qa('.advanced_search_container > section > label > select');
            
            /*
                utility to clear the HTML from within
                a select menu but retain the first
                element - the default value.
            */
            const recycle=(n)=>{
                if( n.type!=='select-one' ){
                    n.value='';
                    return false;
                }
                let clone=n.firstElementChild.cloneNode( true );
                    n.innerHTML='';
                    n.appendChild( clone );
                    n.classList.remove('active')
                return n;
            };
            
            const setactive=(n)=>n.classList.add('active')




            col.forEach( select=>select.addEventListener('change',e=>{
              setactive( e.target );
              
              /*******************************************
                populate the initial Intel/AMD dropdown.. 
                let battle commence!
              */
              if( e.target.id=='env-select' ){
                // find the NEXT select menu to add options to
                // done using the dataset attribute ( data-next )
                let sel=q('select[name="'+e.target.dataset.next+'"]');
                
                let obj=_data[ e.target.value ]; // using original data variable
                
                // ensure the next element is empty
                recycle( sel );
                
                // add all options based upon which Type is selected 
                Object.keys( obj ).forEach( k=>{
                  sel.appendChild( new Option( k, obj[k] ) );
                });
                
                
                return;
              }
              
              
              
              // If the Type or Family is changed, clear all dependant select menus
              if( e.target.dataset.recycle ){
                qa('.dependant').forEach( n=>recycle(n) )
              }
              

              
              
              
              /*******************************************
                Events registered on other dropdowns
              */
              if( e.target.hasAttribute('name') && json[0].hasOwnProperty( e.target.name ) ){
                Object.keys( json ).some( key=>{
                
                    // The "name" is that of the SELECT menu 
                    let name=e.target.name;
                    
                    // The "item" is the value from selected menu
                    let item=json[ key ][ name ];               
                
                
                    if( item==e.target.value ) {
                        let value;
                        
                        // Now search through entire JSON file to find matches to the selected "item"
                        Object.keys( json ).forEach( k=>{
                            obj=json[ k ];
                            if( obj[ name ]==item ){
                                /*
                                    Once the "processor" has been selected any dependant
                                    select menus will have their values added and set as
                                    selected.
                                    
                                    Changing the "family" will clear all dependant select
                                    menus in readiness for a new Processor & associated 
                                    details.
                                */
                                if( e.target.dataset.next ){
                                    /*
                                        Find the next select menu
                                    */
                                    value=obj[ e.target.dataset.next ];
                                    q( 'select[ name="'+e.target.dataset.next+'" ]' ).appendChild( new Option( value, value ) );
                                }else{
                                    /*
                                        target all dependant menus
                                    */
                                    qa( 'section.details select.dependant' ).forEach(n=>{
                                        recycle(n);
                                        value=obj[ n.name ];
                                        n.appendChild( new Option( value, value ) );
                                        n.value=value;
                                    });
                                    
                                    q('textarea[name="notes"]').value=obj.notes
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        console.info( name, item );
                        return true
                    }
                });
              }
            }));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is it. This has solved it thank you very very much! Sorry for tweaking the xls sheet >.>

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple I would structure the data something like;

```
var data = [{
            "manufacturer": "Intel",
            "family": "Celeron",
            "etc": "..",
            "models":[
                     {
                      "model":"12345A",
                      "frequency":[1200,2400],
                      "cores":[2,4,8,16]
                     },
                     {
                      "model":"12345B",
                      "frequency":[1200,2400],
                      "cores":[2,4,8,16]
                     },
                     {
                      "model":"12345C",
                      "frequency":[1200,2400],
                      "cores":[2,4,8,16]
                     },
                     {
                      "model":"12345D",
                      "frequency":[1200,2400],
                      "cores":[2,4,8,16]
                     }
             ]
        },
        {
            "manufacturer": "Intel",
            "name": "Celeron",
            "family": "Celeron D",
            "etc": "..."
        }

    ]
```

And then your JavaScript could be;

```
    //Event on env-select change.

    $('#env-select').on('change', function() {
    
        //Clear and Append Standard "-- Select --" to family-select.
    
        $('#family-select').empty().append('<option value="">-- Select --</option>');
        
        //For each processor in data.
        
        for (entry in data){
        
            //Compare the manufacturer again the value of env-select.
        
            if (String(data[entry]['manufacturer']).valueOf() == String($('#env-select').val()).valueOf()){
                
                //Append family is the family-select if the above is true.
                
                $('#family-select').append('<option value="' + data[entry]['family'] + '">' + data[entry]['family'] + '</option>');
            }
        }
        
    });
    
    //Same as the above but for family-select.

    $('#family-select').on('change', function() {
        $('#processor-select').empty().append('<option value="">-- Select --</option>');
        
        for (entry in data){
            if (String(data[entry]['family']).valueOf() == String($('#family-select').val()).valueOf()){
            
                //Append the processors to processor-select
                for (model in data[entry]['models']){
                    $('#processor-select').append('<option value="' + data[entry]['models'][model]['model'] + '">' + data[entry]['models'][model]['model'] + '</option>');
                
                }
            }
        }
        
    });
```

You may also wish the add the new 'options' to a variable before doing a single empty().append() to reduce the number of DOM interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appendChild() function of the select tag and continue adding your parameters.  You can also do this in jQuery using the append() function. You can get acquainted with the characteristics of different processors [here](https://digitalmasta.com/intel-kf-vs-k-main-differences/). <<input id=""click Me"" value=""click me"" type=""button"" /> <select id=""dropdown""> <option value=""0"">Select Fields

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).